# Div's with same content and same style have different dashed borders

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I created a pen about it, as you see the first `div` has `border-bottom` and the second `border-top`. But the second div's border is different than first's.

http://codepen.io/Chrez/pen/meRxBW

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Screenshot in Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Comment: Looks the same to me

Comment: What browser? They look the same to me in chrome.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fb057u85/ please help me to find difference ?

Comment: Seems to be a Firefox issue, because I can see the difference :)

Comment: Seems like it is. Added a Firefox screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's going to be a rendering issue from your browser. It looks like it's working fine in Chrome but latest Firefox and IE are showing different borders like you said.

If you really must have it fixed I would recommend using pseudo elements with their border-top parameters set to the same value.

```
.first:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top:1px dashed #FFFFFF;
    height: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/st9uesqd/

Comment: thank you, it really is a problem with the Firefox rendering of dashed borders